# d3 zoom not working as in example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get a zoom functionality to work with my d3 network (as per [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)), but am not replicating the behaviour. I first create the zoom variable:

```
 var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 10])
.on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Then I create the svg:

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
.call(zoom);
```

Then finally the function itself:

```
function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale("     + d3.event.scale + ")");
 }
```

However, the network does not allow me to zoom, either by clicking on a node, or from zooming. I attach the full [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbsjfycomdiuod2/test.html?dl=0) if this is needed also.

Does anyone know why I am not getting this behaviour?

Best,

Ben

Comment: Hi, was this using the attached file? Thanks, Ben

Comment: I just tried Firefox, and similarly was not able to zoom...other than just using the default pincher-zooming. I want to be able to zoom by clicking, were you able to do this? Best, Ben

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Mistake 1**

You are doing:

```
function zoomed() {
  contaner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

You should be doing

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Reason the translate/scale should happen to the g DOM(group) which hold the full graph in your case i.e. `variable svg`.

**Mistake 2:**

Append a rectangle to the full length and breadth of SVG to capture the zoom events.

```
var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Zfcx4ZrwMugemghByfO?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much for going through the effort of making the whole thing work. Really appreciate it! I'll reference you in the final thing. Best, Ben

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the code is that the svg element selection that was received from this code:

```
d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
```

was later on continued with `.append("g")`
once you use append, the selection is moved to the element you appended.

So in fact, you should have split the code into 2 variables already when you defined the svg variable like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom);
```

(The same bug exists in the working example at this accepted answer example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701811/4884749)